# Git diff with -m

Tags: git, git-diff

I've a merge conflict, and when I do a `git diff` I'm shown diff in combined format. The documentation for `git help diff`, where it explains the combined diff format, it's mentioned that I could use `-m` with any of the diff commands. But `git diff` wouldn't take a `-m` option. `git help diff-tree` however documents `-m` option.

I'm trying to look at diffs of the file between each merge parent, one at a time, potentially using the `-m` switch. Yes, I could use commands like `git diff :{1,2}:/path/to/file` or `git diff :{1,3}:/path/to/file`, but given a combined diff output, how do I use the `-m` switch?

Comment: What do you mean with "wouldn't take the -m option"? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh well, `Note also that you can give the -m option to any of these commands to force generation of diffs with individual parents of a merge` led me believe that I could choose individual parents when viewing merge conflicts. I now realize it won't take options, but is used to view diffs in merge commits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my own question: the `-m` flag to `git diff` or `git show`, when applied to a merge commit, individually lists how that merge commit differs from each of its parent, one by one.

Say, if you've a layout as below:

```
--X--A--,
         \
  --X--B--M--
         /
--X--C--'
```

`git show -m M` concatenates outputs of `git diff A M`, then `git diff B M` and `git diff C M`. `git show M` shows the diff information, but in a combined diff format. The `-m` flag is also useful in cases where git omits diff output completely